# Set angularjs directive attribute from a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular Bootstrap typehead directive, which can be configured from HTML like so:

```
<div ng-controller="search">
  <input typeahead-focus-first="false" />
</div>
```

Is it possible to set the 'typeahead-focus-first' attribute from the ng-controller instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller scope has a property

```
$scope.typeahead = true;
```

then

```
<div ng-controller="search">
  <input ng-if="typeahead" typeahead-focus-first="false" />
  <input ng-if="!typeahead" />
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-controller="search">
  <input typeahead-focus-first="typeahead" />
</div>
```

The second method requires your typeahead directive to be able to parse the typeahead expression.  There are several ways to accomplish this (isolated scope or $parse for example).  The typeahead directive in angular bootstrap does this for you, so the second method should work.

EDIT:  As a directive

```
.directive('search', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><input typeahead-focus-first="false" /></div>',
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //this is where you want to do your DOM manipulation (if any)
        }
    };
})
```

Usage:

```
<search></search>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I was looking for a solution where this can be set from JS and not mentioned at all in the HTML; as I have several typeheads and all have this setting, defining it each time is clutter.

Comment: As a general best practice in angular, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM in your controllers.  The option you are looking for is probably the creation of a custom directive.

Answer (score 1):

the typeahead property is evalued from `attr` with this expression:

```
var focusFirst = originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadFocusFirst) !== false;
```

so you should set a variable in your scope

```
$scope.typeahead = true;
```

and then

```
<div ng-controller="search">
    <input typeahead-focus-first="{{typeahead}}" />
</div>
```

Typeahead source [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js).

EDIT:
As has emerged from the comments seems you want to edit the behaviour from the controller without writing anything on the dom. Unfortunately I think this is not possible because the variable governing that behaviour is saved inside the closure at compile time and is not modificable after the component has been linked. You need to recompile the component to change that behaviour with, for example an ng-if.

Comment: I don't think $eval works with {{}}.  scope.$eval is equivalent to $parse(expression)(scope).

Comment: It works but only during the first linking phase, the typeahead will be set to either true or false depending on the scope value while the component is being compiled. It will not be two way binded.